# switch statement and scopes in ES2015

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, v8

Consider this ES2015 module and the behavior when run in node v4.4.5.

```
'use strict'

const outer = 1

switch ('foo') {
  case 'bar':
    const heyBar = 'HEY_BAR'
    break
  case 'baz':
    const heyBaz = 'HEY_BAZ'
    break
  default:
    const heyDefault = 'HEY_DEFAULT'
}
console.log(
  outer, // 1, makes sense, same top-level scope
  heyBar, // undefined. huh? I thought switch did NOT create a child scope
  heyBaz, // undefined. huh? I thought switch did NOT create a child scope
  heyDefault) // 'HEY_DEFAULT' makes sense
```

This seems internally inconsistent to me. If the switch statement did NOT create a lexical scope, I would expect all the `hey*` variables to be part of the main scope and to all behave consistently. If the switch statement did create a lexical scope, I would still expect them to be consistent, but the variables declared in the `case` clauses behave like they are in a child scope, whereas the variables in the `default` clause behaves like it is in the outer scope.

**My question is** are there any child scopes involved in a switch statement, and if so what are the details of how they behave?

In node v6.4.0, the behavior is different. It looks like the switch block does indeed create a child block scope.

```
ReferenceError: heyBar is not defined
```

And that seems a lot more straightforward to understand.

Comment: Btw, you can create a per case scope if you add a block scope to each case: ` case 'bar': { const heyBar = 'HEY_BAR'; break }`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't reproduce your behavior at all. I immediately get a `ReferenceError` (Node 6.4.0 and current Firefox for that matter):

```
ReferenceError: heyBar is not defined
```

Which seems like the correct behavior to me. AFAIK `switch` statements with brackets DO create a block, and thus a lexical scope for block-scoped entities. The `case` statements themselves do not create their own blocks.

If we expand this example with a `foo` case in the `switch` statement, it throws a `ReferenceError` as well:

```
'use strict'

const outer = 1

switch ('foo') {
  case 'bar':
    const heyBar = 'HEY_BAR'
    break
  case 'baz':
    const heyBaz = 'HEY_BAZ'
    break
  case 'foo':
    const heyFoo = 'HEY_FOO'
    break
  default:
    const heyDefault = 'HEY_DEFAULT'
}
console.log(
  outer,
  heyFoo,
  heyBar,
  heyBaz,
  heyDefault) // ReferenceError: heyFoo is not defined
```

**Reference**

[Here is the section in the spec: 13.12.11 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-switch-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

```
5. Let blockEnv be NewDeclarativeEnvironment(oldEnv).
6. Perform BlockDeclarationInstantiation(CaseBlock, blockEnv).
```

Where [`CaseBlock`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-switch-statement-static-semantics-containsduplicatelabels) is the block statement of the switch case.

This roughly translates to:

Create a new block environment in the block of the switch statement (`switch { <-here-> }`) and instantiate all block level declarations (such as `let`, `const` or block level function declarations).

Comment: Interesting. Does seem to have changed between node v4 and node v6.

Comment: You wrote that you are using Node `6.4.0`? The change probably just means that v6 is closer to the ES2016 specification than v4.

Comment: I'm trying both to understand the difference. I'm also looking for clear docs about what is the to-spec behavior for ES2015.

Comment: I've got node 6.3.1 and what I'm seeing is that nothing declared in case or default is visible outside the switch, even if the branch evaluates to true. Which is what I'd expect, actually.

Comment: @PeterLyons - Did you go read the relevant portion of the ES2015 spec?  That's the doc for this.

Comment: @PeterLyons If you're using a debugger to examine the variables, this could explain the behaviour. Debuggers lie.

Comment: @jfriend00 If you mean [section 13.12 of the ECMA-262 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-switch-statement), while I'm aware of the existence of this document, it contains zero comprehensible information for me in the formal spec format.

Comment: You just asked about spec references: `I'm also looking for clear docs about what is the to-spec behavior for ES2015.` I added a rough translation of what these lines mean to the answer.

Comment: @PeterLyons - I added an answer that tries to walk you through the spec for a switch/case to show you why a switch creates a new scope, but a case does not.

Answer (score 3):

The code above throws `ReferenceError: heyDefault is not defined` in strict mode if there's no `heyBar`, and it throws `ReferenceError: heyBar` otherwise.

`switch` creates a scope for `switch (...) { ... }` statement, scopes for `case` statements are not created. See [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let).

Answer (score 2):

The body of a `switch` statement creates a new block scope.  Each individual `case` clause or `default` clause do not automatically create a new block scope.

The definitive reference for understanding scoping and the `switch` statement is, of course, the [ES2016 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-switch-statement-static-semantics-lexicallyscopeddeclarations).  It is, however, some work to figure out what it's really saying.  I will try to walk you through what I can follow from that specification.

**Define Important Terms**

First off, a switch statement is defined to be this:

```
SwitchStatement:
    switch ( Expression ) CaseBlock
```

And, a CaseBlock is this:

```
CaseBlock:
    { CaseClauses }
    { CaseClauses DefaultClause CaseClauses }

CaseClauses:
    CaseClause
    CaseClauses CaseClause

CaseClause:
    case Expression : StatementList

DefaultClause:
    default : StatementList
```

So a `CaseBlock` is the body of the `switch` statement (the code that includes all the cases).

This is what we are expecting, but the term `CaseBlock` as defined above is important for other spec references.

**CaseBlock creates new Scope**

Then, in [13.2.14 Runtime Semantics: BlockDeclarationInstantiation( code, env )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-blockdeclarationinstantiation), we can see that a CaseBlock causes a new scope to be created.

> When a Block or CaseBlock production is evaluated a new declarative
>   Environment Record is created and bindings for each block scoped
>   variable, constant, function, generator function, or class declared in
>   the block are instantiated in the Environment Record.

Since the `CaseBlock` is the body of the `switch` statement, this means that the body of the `switch` statement creates one new block scope (a container for new let/const declarations).

**CaseClause Adds to Existing Scope (does not create its own scope)**

Then, in [13.12.6 Static Semantics: LexicallyScopedDeclarations](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-switch-statement-static-semantics-lexicallyscopeddeclarations), it describes how lexically scoped declarations are collected by the interpreter at parse time.  Here's the actual text from the spec (explanation will follow):

> CaseBlock : { CaseClauses DefaultClause CaseClauses }
>
> 1. If the first CaseClauses is present, let declarations be the  LexicallyScopedDeclarations of the first CaseClauses.
> 2. Else let declarations be a new empty List.
> 3. Append to declarations the elements of the LexicallyScopedDeclarations of the DefaultClause.
> 4. If the second CaseClauses is not present, return declarations.
> 5. Else return the result of appending to declarations the elements of the LexicallyScopedDeclarations of the second CaseClauses.
>
> CaseClauses : CaseClauses CaseClause
>
> 1. Let declarations be LexicallyScopedDeclarations of CaseClauses.
> 2. Append to declarations the elements of the LexicallyScopedDeclarations of CaseClause.
> 3. Return declarations.
>
> CaseClause : case Expression : StatementList
>
> 1. If the StatementList is present, return the LexicallyScopedDeclarations of StatementList.
> 2. Else return a new empty List.
>
> DefaultClause : default : StatementList
>
> 1. If the StatementList is present, return the LexicallyScopedDeclarations of StatementList.
> 2. Else return a new empty List.

So, basically what this is saying is that the first caseClause creates a LexicallyScopedDeclarations object.  And, then each DefaultClause or CaseClause that follows appends to that declarations object.  This is how the spec describes building up all the declarations within a scope.

A `CaseClause` appends to the existing declarations object, it does not create its own.  That means it does not create its own scope, but instead uses the containing scope.

You could, of course, define a block within a `CaseClause` and that block would then be its own scope, but a `CaseClause` does not require a block declaration so thus it does not, by default, create a new scope.

**Runtime Semantics: Evaluation**

Then, there is further explanation about how things work at runtime in [13.12.11 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-switch-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

> SwitchStatement: switch(Expression) CaseBlock
>
> 1. Let exprRef be the result of evaluating Expression.
> 2. Let switchValue be ? GetValue(exprRef).
> 3. Let oldEnv be the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment.
> 4. Let blockEnv be NewDeclarativeEnvironment(oldEnv).
> 5. Perform BlockDeclarationInstantiation(CaseBlock, blockEnv).
> 6. Set the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment to blockEnv.
> 7. Let R be the result of performing CaseBlockEvaluation of CaseBlock with  argument switchValue.
> 8. Set the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment to oldEnv.
> 9. Return R.

The operative step here are steps 4 and 5 where a new block environment is created for the `CaseBlock`.  If you follow on in the text of 13.12.11, no new block environment is created for a `CaseClause` within the `CaseBlock`.

> CaseClause: case Expression: StatementList
>
> 1. Return the result of evaluating StatementList.

So, there you have it.  A `CaseBlock` creates a new block scope.  A `CaseClause` does not (unless you explicitly define a block yourself within the `CaseClause`).

Answer (score 2):

With `{` `}`, encapsulate each `case` that contains a scoped declaration to create a new block scope:

```
const var1 = true;

switch (var1) {
  case true: {
    const var2 = 0;
    break;
  }
  case false: {
    const var2 = 1;
    break;
  }
  default: {
    const var2 = 2;
  }
}
```